# cambiar el puerto del servidor jasper

Tags: punteros, jasper-reports, server, jaspersoft

Buen día, estoy configurando un servidor jasper http://localhost/ este por defecto se instaló con puerto 8080 pero este esta siendo utilizado por tomcat9.exe.
Por lo que al querer correr el servidor dice que el puerto rechaza la conexión, alguien sabe que se debe de hacer para cambiar el puerto de mi jasper Server ?

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/

esta es la dirección que me proporciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: pues estoy usando apache de xampp para mi proyecto web el cual tiene que consumir los reportes, el problema es que si cambio de puerto el tomcat no me funciona correctamente el apache por lo que mi opción es cambiar el servidor, el problema es que no he usado nunca jasper por eso estoy preguntando si alguien sabe como se cambia de puerto.

Comment: ha ok y has intentado buscar en la documentacion de jasper como cambiar el puerto o como cambiar el puerto de tomcat???

Comment: la documentación para cambiar el puerto de jasper, solo he encontrado las 6 pero estoy buscando la de la 8.0.0_win_x86_64

Comment: probaste la de la 6???

Comment: te comento estoy usando jaspersoft 6.18 que es el mas reciente y no se si si dará problemas de compatibilidad

Comment: si no lo intentas nadie sabrá que has intentado...